# How can I send a notification in case a internet connection is made after the app is killed?

Tags: android, service, push-notification

In my project if there was no internet connection when the app was killed I want the user to receive a notification when there is an internet connection available. I was doing this by starting a service on the onCreate() of the Activity , and then once the app was killed and the service onTaskRemoved was triggered , the following code would happen. But as you can see I basically have a while structure that runs while there is no connection and there is a connection ( and the while structure ends) the notification is launched. But I don't think that this is the right approach to the code and actually it only works if the gap between killing the app and making a wifi connection is small. Also I believe that the code runs in the main thread because I only get "Application Terminated" on the Terminal once the notification is launched. How can I fix this? Once again, I want the user to get a notification once there is an internet connection available after the app was killed.

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
  if(!isConnected(this)) {
    while (!isConnected(this)) {
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Home.CHANNEL_ID).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Network").setContentText("Network Available");
    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nNotifyMgr.notify(1, builder.build());
  }
}
```

Comment: `service` won't work in background try using `JobShedular` and `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is killed and you still want to get notification via your app weather device is connected with wifi then you need to use **Broad cast Receiver**. Broad cast receiver works weather your app is on back ground, foreground or killed. You can use below code

1) Create a class

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (checkWifiConnect()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "wifi has connected");
        // TODO
    }        
}

private boolean checkWifiConnect() {
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null
        && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
        && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
}
```

2) You need to register your receiver in manifest as well. Use below code

```
<receiver android:name=".your.namepackage.here.ConnectivityReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is part of [background restricted broadcast actions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) . So it should not registered statically in manifest .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but do I also need to initialize the broadcast receiver in my main activity?